# linux shell script: how to move all sub folders with a given name?

Tags: linux, bash, directory, mv

I'd like to move all sub-folders starting with a given suffix (Blah_ in the example) into an other directory using a linux bash script. Here's what the script looks like:

```
srcDir="/home/me/"
archiveDir="/Archive/"
prefix="Blah_"
mv -v -f "$srcDir$prefix*" -t $archiveDir
```

Though there are a lot of directories starting with 'Blah_', inside /home/me, this leads to the following error message:

```
mv: cannot stat `/home/me/Blah_*': No such file or directory
```

Now I'm curious whats wrong here. How must the above script be changed in order to move all subfolders starting with 'Blah' into the archive folder?

Comment: Remove the quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mv -v -f ${srcDir}${prefix}* -t $archiveDir
```

in this case if you quote, * will be interpreted literally

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
find   /home/me   -type   d   -name   "Blah_*"   -exec   mv   -i  {}  /Archive \;
```